# Python Password Prigram

Tags: python

I am creating a password program for my programming class, the requirements are:

8 Characters/1 letter/1 Digit/Alphanumeric only

The problem is the .isalpha or .isdigit cancel each other out because they require all of the string to be letters or numbers.

Is there anyways I can make it check if atleast 1 character is a number or letter

```
###############################
# PROLOG SECTION
# new_password.py
# Program to check a user's proposed
# password.
# (today's date goes here)
# (programmer names go here)
# (tester names go here)
# Possible future enhancements:
# Unresolved bugs:
###############################

###############################
# PROCESSING INITIALIZATION SECTION
###############################
# code goes here
minlength = 8
valid = False


###############################
# PROCESSING SECTION
# Branching code:
# Looping code:
###############################
# code goes here
# get the user input
password = str(input("Type in your password: "))
    # test the password length
if len(password) >= minlength:
    # test for all alphanumeric
    if password.isalnum():
        if password.isalpha():
            if password.isdigit():
        # if the password meets BOTH conditions, set valid to true
                valid = True
            else:
                #otherwise, give the user a meaningful error message
                print("Error, password does not contain a number.")
        else:
            #otherwise, give the user a meaningful error message
            print("Error, password does not contain a letter.")
    else:
        # otherwise, give the user a meaningful error message
        print("Error, password is not alphanumeric.")
else:
    # otherwise, give the user a meaningful error message
    print("Error, password is less than",minlength,"characters.")
###############################
# CLEANUP, TERMINATION, and EXIT 
# SECTION
###############################
# code goes here
# print informational messages
# if the password meets the condition (at least 8 characters)
if valid == True:
    # print the "successful" message
    print("Your new password is valid.")
else:
    # otherwise, print the "unsuccessful" message
    print("Your new password is not valid.")
```

Comment: Use Regex! THE best option to solve your problem in a easy and best way :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `any()`:

```
valid = any(c.isalpha() for c in password) and any(c.isdigit() for c in password)
```

This will satisfy the requirement that there is at least 1 alpha character and 1 digit. Combine that with `password.isalnum()` and the length check and you should be able to vet your passwords.

Comment: This is great! I have a question: if I try to do this same thing in a `for loop` inside an if statement it doesn't work, I get an error, . i.e. `for i in x:` `if any(i.isalpha()):`  I wonder why...

Comment: [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) works on an iterable (e.g. list, tuple, string, etc) checking each element for "truthiness". Your example attempts to operate on a `bool` (the return value of `isalpha()`) and therefore fails.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Yes, I get that. What I don't get is how that's not the case in your code. I am trying to wrap my brain around your code but I can't understand how that's different from my code. In `c.isalpha()` how is `c` an iterable? BTW: you probably should put `()` after the `c.isdigit` as well, otherwise it returns `True` even when it's `False`

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing out the missing parens for `isdigit`, fixed. Regarding `any()`, my code passes the generator expression `(c.isalpha() for c in password)` to `any()`. I could also have used the list comprehension `[c.isalpha() for c in password]`. In either case an iterable containing boolean values is passed to `any()` which checks each element until it finds the first "true" one, in which case it returns True, otherwise False. For example `[c.isalpha() for c in 'abcd1234']` returns the list `[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]`. Passing that to `any()` returns True.

Comment: similarly `[c.isalpha() for c in '54321']` returns `[False, False, False, False, False]` for which `any()` returns False. The generator expression is similar: `(c.isalpha() for c in 'abcd1234')` returns a generator which `any()` can iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

There are several (innumerable?) ways to accomplish this.

Looking at the code you have, you've taken care of testing the length and making sure you have only alphanumeric characters.  So consider some candidate password which has cleared these two hurdles.  You want to let through any candidate that contains at least one letter *and* at least one digit.

So figure out what you want to **stop** (there are basically two 'bad' cases), and how you could identify these with `.isalpha` and `.isdigit`.  (i.e. once you know what the 'bad' candidates look like, what would they give you for each of those methods?)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex. OR
If you only want to check if at least 1 char is number or a letter. Then use this:

```
    #To check for at least 1 digit
    >>> str="yogi123yogi"
    >>> [chr.isdigit() for chr in str]
    [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

any() comes in handy here:

```
>>> any([chr.isalpha() for chr in str])
True
```

Similarly check of 1 alphabet also:

```
>>> any([chr.isalpha() for chr in str])
True
```

Note: Well you can process the above information from `isdigit()` and `isalpha` to figure out the total count and match with the password length.

`Total num of digits + Total num of alphabets == Password Length`

Else don't accept the password.